# Using Margin in TabControl.ItemContainerStyle clips Headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Want to add some margin for initial `TabControl` headers:
[image]

use this `ItemContainerStyle`

```xml
<TabControl mahapps:TabControlHelper.Underlined="SelectedTabItem">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,40,0"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

result:
[image]

---

**Padding**
Using `Padding` instead of `Margin` is not an option due to `Underline`
[image]

---

How to save all letters? Letters are good fellows.

---

**(Update) Negative Margin**
Tried `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,0,0"/>`
[image]

Comment: Can you try `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="-10,0,0,0"/>`

Comment: @dhilmathy Tried, still no margin but the first header is clipped from the other side.